# Orthogonal projection of a vector on a subspace

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I have to determine the orthogonal projection of the vector v=(2, 4, 2) on the subspace Span(v1, v2). I know that V=(v1, v2, v3) where v1=(1, 0, 1), v2=(5, 1, 1,) and v3=(4, -1, 0). So far I have applied the Gram-Schmidt process on V to determine an orthonormal basis where, u1=(1/√2, 0, 1/√2), u2=(2/3, 1/3, -2/3) and u3=(√2/6, -2√2/3, -√2/6). I have tried using the projection formula once more:

proj_span(v)=((v.u1)/(u1.u1)).u1+(v.u2)/(u1.u2)).u2

and get an ortogonal vector of (26/9, 4/9, -2/3). So my question is, is this true or am I completely off track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check yourself actually (with a bit more work): does your answer lie in Span$(v_1,v_2)$? (that's a row-reduction problem) If $w$ is your answer, is $v-w$ orthogonal to $w$? (that's a dot-product calculation)

Comment: process is correct.. just check the last coordinate.. I am getting it as $\frac{10}{9}$ instead of $\frac{-2}{3}$